# JqGrid - post data (with redirect) to controller action results in 404

Tags: post, jqgrid, action

I have a JqGrid with navigation extra button. In onClickButton event I want to post row data to another view, not only one value which could be done via action link. I need to be able to pass more variables with their values to perform parametric create action with prefilled values [for hidden inputs] and show in view.  In this case I am sending only 2. JSON would more suitable. But let's continue.

```
.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#rolesPager',   
{
 caption: "",position: 'first',buttonicon: "ui-icon-plus", 
 title: $.jgrid.nav.addtitle,
 onClickButton: function () {
   $.post("/Administration/Roles/CreateWithParams", { 
        foreignColumn: 'WEB_USER_id',    foreignValue: '1' }, function (data) {
           location = "/Administration/Roles/CreateWithParams";
   }).fail(function (error)
   {
     alert(error);
   });
 }});
```

Then I have a controller action:

```
    //
    // GET: /Administration/Roles/Create
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateWithParams(string foreignColumn, int foreignValue)
    {
        ViewBag.WEB_ROLE_id = new SelectList(db.WEB_ROLE, "WEB_ROLE_id", "name");
        ViewBag.WEB_USER_id = foreignValue;
        return View();
    }
```

Data are sent but rendering its view fails in 404 - Resource not found. In my post method I have only 2 parameters, but there can be sent as JSON - as just one variable passed to controller . I think that this has something to do with

```
location = "url";
```

statement where data are probably lost or changes something. I would need somehow find a way how to make the view of action CreateWithParams rendered (does not matter if GET or POST) with displaying of passed post values. For create action I do not need to pass model data, just previous values but called view wil use model. Every post action examples just returns callback but not display a controller action view using sent data. Or is this completely bad approach and it this is not possible? Or call another action from with resending data as result of CreateWithParams action? If it so could some point me to right direction?

Comment: I solved the problem other way, I created hidden form with hidden submit button and trigger it when user clicks navigation button, so in action CreateWithParams I just replace parameters to FormCollection. Working like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that ajax has its limitation and cannot be redirected with parameters easily. So hidden forms on a page must come to scene.

```
<form action="/Administration/Roles/CreateWithParams" 
      style="display: none" method="post" 
      name="roles_hiddenForm" id="#roles_hiddenForm" 
      novalidate="novalidate">

<input type="hidden" value="2" name="WEB_USER_id" id="WEB_USER_id">
<input type="hidden" value="WEB_USER_id" name="ForeignKeyColumn" id="ForeignKeyColumn">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="ForeignKeyValue" id="ForeignKeyValue">
<input type="submit" name="roles_hiddenSubmit" id="roles_hiddenSubmit"></form>
```

and js I modified as:

```
.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#rolesPager',
{
  caption: "",position: 'first',
  buttonicon: "ui-icon-plus", 
  title: $.jgrid.nav.addtitle,
  onClickButton: function () {
     $("#roles_hiddenSubmit").click();
  }
});
```